# Please explain why my account balance is almost 0

Tags: balances, address.transfer

I sent some ethereum to an account and the incoming transaction shows up. Also there is an outgoing transaction of a small amount of ethereum, but the final balance of the account is close to zero. How is this possible?

https://ethplorer.io/address/0x3709965a82999eb7c38535dbae22fc54a08b692c

Comment: Is this you account? It is possible someone else has the seed phrase / private key of it?

Comment: Unfortunately yes to both... the account was generated programmatically by an application I am working on. I have improved the key generation now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Ethereum transaction costs some amount of Eth to fund the transaction.
e.g in your case it costs 0.022 Eth approx.

[image: tx cost]

So in addition to the amount you transferred, you also paid this fee(called gas fee).

See your transaction for details: https://ethplorer.io/tx/0xf412896a1d7f046db3c1e783bc0aeec52b09627ab6fb50eababf9899edea1bc2#pageTab=transfers

Answer (score 0):

Because an insane transaction fee was paid for the second transaction. The gas price for it was 1091 Gwei, when 6 or 7 would have been more than enough.

Comment: That's right! The thing is, I didn't send the second transaction... I realize that someone might have my private key, which is bad, but anyway: I don't really see what's the use of sending a small transaction with an insane fee instad of just stealing the assets?

Comment: @mybinaryromance could be that a gas fee bidding was between bots was happening. If multiple bots have the private key for this address, and they will all compete for who can empty it first.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you :)